# Why won't Microsoft Edge respond when I use it with VerbAce-Pro?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, extension

I've installed `VerbAce-Pro` [Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/verbace-pro-extension/cogaimpmgeoeppkjiekhplafgfdplgcc) in `Microsoft Edge` yet; it gets a non-response status when I started typing something unless the `VerbAce-Pro` program is closed.

I've recorded a DMP file, but it's too large. Do I need to upload it for you?

[image]

My Edge info:

[image]

My windows info:

[image]

Comment: Are you using Chromium Edge?  I think VerbAce is a Chrome Extension so you would need Chromium Edge to try it.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate the exact version of Edge you are using.  You should also include the version of Windows 10 you are using.

Comment: @John Yes, I'm using the new Edge not the legacy.

Comment: @Ramhound done.

Comment: Have you enabled the option that allows extensions from the Google (Extension) Store?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes and I'm using other Chrome-based extensions without problems.

Comment: Since this extension requires the use of third-party software to function properly, have you contacted the author of that third-party software and/or extension, and reported the problem.  Have you confirmed the problem does or doesn't exist in Google Chome?  While based on Chromium, Edge isn't Google Chrome, so any differences might be the reason the extension doesn't work right.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I've just tested it on Chrome and it's working without problems but I didn't contact the author yet.

Comment: That tells me the extension is simply not compatible with Microsoft Edge at this time

Comment: How do I make it compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension isn't compatible with MS Edge as the author said to me:

> Dear Sir, Thank you for your message. Since Edge is only 7% we don't
> support it now. But you should be able to use FF - if you have a
> problem please let me know.
> -- Amir Z. VerbAce Support Team.